# Execution failed for task ' app:processArm64ReleaseManifest' [Ionic]

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm having an error after I execute code

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

I tried removing and and adding android platform but the same error shows up.

[image]

When I run

```
  ionic cordova build --stacktrace
```

[image]

Comment: What happened when you did what the suggestion says to do?

Comment: It says UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 

I think there's something wrong with my AndroidManifest but I didn't change anything with it. I tried running it using 'ionic serve --browser chrome' it runs but when I try to get the APK it gives me an error. Please help :(

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error when you get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Comment: added the screenshot of the error I used ionic cordova build --stacktrace

Comment: found something to solve it?